# Use SASS to create a list of classes from a list of colors with color in the class name

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to automate a large list of background color classes with SASS. I have defined a list of color variables. I'd like to automatically generate 2 classes for each color, a solid background class and a transparent background class.

This is what I'm working with, but I'm pretty sure I have some syntax problems because it doesn't work.

```
$colors-list: $color1 $color2 $color3;
@each $current-color in $colors-list {
    .{$current-color}-bg { 
        background-color: $current-color;
    }
    .trans-{$current-color}-bg { 
        background-color: rgba ($current-color, 0.9);
    }
}
```

What I want for the output is:

```
.color1-bg{ 
    background-color: #00ff00;
    }

.trans-color1-bg{ 
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.9); 
    }
```

Hopefully this is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm, I'm not sure what you meant by "you want that output", as that's not valid CSS.  The way you have it here only works for named colors, and won't work with hex values.

```
$color1: red;
$color2: yellow;
$color3: green;

$colors-list: $color1 $color2 $color3;
@each $current-color in $colors-list {
    .#{$current-color}-bg { 
        background-color: $current-color;
    }
    .trans-#{$current-color}-bg { 
        background-color: rgba($current-color, 0.9);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.red-bg {
  background-color: red;
}

.trans-red-bg {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.yellow-bg {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.trans-yellow-bg {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9);
}

.green-bg {
  background-color: green;
}

.trans-green-bg {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.9);
}
```

### Edit

To use with hex values you can use a map:

```
$color-map: (
  red: #f00,
  green: #0f0,
  blue: #00f
);

@each $name, $color in $color-map {
  .#{$name}-bg {
    background: $color;
  }
  .#{$name}-bg-transparent {
    background-color: rgba($color, 0.9);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.red-bg {
  background: #f00;
}

.red-bg-transparent {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.green-bg {
  background: #0f0;
}

.green-bg-transparent {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9);
}

.blue-bg {
  background: #00f;
}

.blue-bg-transparent {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9);
}
```

Comment: you're correct. I changed the original question to show valid css output. But I'm still getting errors. I'm not using the standard named colors... is there some way to get it to work with hex colors?